# Rails 3 - how to find last inserted ID from mysql table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, lastinsertid

in my controller I have following sequence of commands:

```
SAVE DATA INTO FIRST TABLE

_get ID of inserted item into table from first step_

SAVE DATA INTO SECOND TABLE WITH ID FROM FIRST COMMAND

if FIRST.save && SECOND.save
 do something
```

And I am wondering, how to get id of item, which is immediately inserted into database... I tried to googling, but I can't find this information...

Thanks in advance for your hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# SAVE DATA INTO FIRST TABLE
first_instance = FirstModel.new( :foo => :bar )
first_save = first_instance.save

# _get ID of inserted item into table from first step_
first_instance_id = first_instance.id

# SAVE DATA INTO SECOND TABLE WITH ID FROM FIRST COMMAND
second_save = SecondModel.new( :first_model_id => first_instance_id ).save

if first_save && second_save
  # do something
end
```

Comment: yes, but this unfortunately I can't do, look at my structure -- but maybe will not other way how to do...

Comment: Your structure's not very clear then... your first two "commands" match this answer. Why not paste your actual code?

Comment: Here is my currently controller: http://pastebin.com/UVV8XBXa and way, how I am trying to solve this situation

Comment: I am struggling with one problem yet... I got the ID of last inserted item, but I don't know why -- I can't save the ID from first table to second to save... If I try: puts first_instance_id -- so I get a number, but this number is not  to save to column with datatype "int(11) not null" -- I tried also "first_instance_id.to_i", ut unfortunately without success... Did not meet anyone with similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Could you just search your database by the `updated_at` field in your model?

To get the most recent record:

```
@model1 = Model1.order("updated_at DESC").limit(1)
```

or better yet, upon saving Model1 in the first place:

```
@model1 = model1.save
```

To assign:

```
@model2.model1_id = @model1.id
```

**Note:** if you actually want to save the ID of a specific record, finding the last isn't the best way to go.

This is because another record could be inserted by a different user, right after you inserted Model1 and right before you call Model2.

If you want the two to save together or not at all, you can look into transactions: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

If you're happy with Model1 saving on its own before worrying about Model2, then simply assign the variables as I did above.

Answer (score 1):

After saving a model, you can access it's `id` variable:

```
@user = User.new
puts @user.id
# => nil
@user.save
puts @user.id
# => 1
```